# Userform Login for Users - Error: Select from Workbook Problem

Tags: excel, vba

I have changed a bit some code and now when i try to login as a normal user, it gives me the following error: "Method Select of Object '_Worksheet" I tried changing again the code but still it the same error. With the Admin user, its all ok. What i googled was that maybe because the sheets are on xlVeryHidden but before i had it like that and it worked fine...

```
Private Sub btnEntrar_Click()
    'Declare the variables
    Dim AddData As Range, Current As Range
    Dim user As Variant, Code As Variant
    Dim PName As Variant, AName As Variant, UName As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet, ws5 As Worksheet
    Dim result As Integer
    Dim TitleStr As String
    Dim msg As VbMsgBoxResult

    'Set the pages variables
    Set ws = Worksheets("Ingreso")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Ingresos - Usuarios")
    Set ws3 = Worksheets("Supervisores")
    Set ws4 = Worksheets("LookupList")
    Set ws5 = Worksheets("Registros")

    'Variables
    user = Me.txtUser.Value
    Code = Me.txtPass.Value
    TitleStr = "Password check"
    result = 0
    Set Current = ws.Range("M3")

    'Error handler
    On Error GoTo errHandler:

    'Destination location for login storage
    Set AddData = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

'Check the login and passcode for the Administrator
    If user <> "" And Not IsNumeric(user) And Code <> "" Then
        For Each AName In ws.Range("R4:R6")
            'If AName = Code Then 'Use this for passcode text
            If AName = Code And AName.Offset(0, -1) = user Then ' Puede usar texto Y números
                MsgBox "Inicio como Administrador de: " & user

                'record user login
                AddData.Value = user
                AddData.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now
                'Add usernmae to the worksheet
                Current.Value = user
                'Change variable if the condition is meet
                result = 1
                'Unload the form
                ws.Visible = True   'Cambiar para que lo tome de la tabla de permisos y no manual como ahora, usar el cod de abajo
                ws2.Visible = True
                ws3.Visible = True
                ws4.Visible = True
                ws5.Visible = True
                ws.Select
                Unload Me

                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next AName
    End If

    'Check user login with loop
    If user <> "" And Not IsNumeric(user) And Code <> "" Then
        For Each UName In ws.Range("R11:R19")
            'If UName = Code Then 'Use this for passcode text
            If UName = Code And UName.Offset(0, -1) = user Then ' Puede usar texto Y números
                MsgBox "Ingreso satisfactorio para: " & user

                'record user login
                AddData.Value = user
                AddData.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now
                'Add usernmae to the worksheet
                Current.Value = user

                Set PName = Hoja2.Range("E:E").Find(What:=user, LookIn:=xlValues)

                'unhide worksheet for user
                If PName.Offset(0, 2) = "Ingreso" Then
                Set ws = Worksheets(PName.Offset(0, 2).Value)
                ws.Visible = True
                End If

                If PName.Offset(0, 3) = "Ingresos - Usuarios" Then
                Set ws2 = Worksheets(PName.Offset(0, 3).Value)
                ws2.Visible = True
                End If

                If PName.Offset(0, 3) = "Supervisores" Then
                Set ws3 = Worksheets(PName.Offset(0, 3).Value)
                ws3.Visible = True
                End If

                If PName.Offset(0, 4) = "Registros" Then
                Set ws4 = Worksheets(PName.Offset(0, 4).Value)
                ws4.Visible = True
                End If

                If PName.Offset(0, 5) = "LookupList" Then
                Set ws5 = Worksheets(PName.Offset(0, 5).Value)
                ws5.Visible = True
                End If

                'show sheet tab if hidden
                ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = True

                'Change variable if the condition is meet
                result = 1

                'Unload the form
                ws3.Select
                Unload Me
                'Inicio Automático el Multi
                InicioSuperv
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next UName
    End If
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: @BigBen Thats one problem, it does not show me where the error its located...

Comment: If i don´t hide the sheets, it does not give any error, so i suppose the error goes over that way...

Comment: Use a breakpoint at strategic locations (and step thru it with F8) to figure out where it errors.

Comment: Are you trying to `Select` a hidden sheet? Or are you trying to hide *all* sheets (you can't do that)?

Comment: Consider using the defined worksheet visibility enum instead of Boolean literals, too.

Comment: When they log in, they are all hidden. If the sheet its on the table where the values are taken to check if they are available for them, they should unhide.